# Choose Amazon S3 storage class using Laravel Filesystem

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

Amazon S3 has different [storage classes](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/storage-classes/), with different price brackets.

I was wondering if there's a way I can choose a storage class in Laravel's Filesystem / Cloud Storage solution?

It would be good to choose a class on a per upload basis so I can choose throughout my application, not just once in a configuration file.

Comment: You can configure multiple "disks" in laravel each pointed to a different s3 bucket using the different storage classes

Answer (score 10):

To pass additional options to flysystem you have to use `getDriver()`

```
Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->put(
    'sample.txt',
    'This is a demo',
    [
        'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY'
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be used in Laravel 7

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put(
    'file path',
    $request->file('file'),
    [
        'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD|REDUCED_REDUNDANCY|STANDARD_IA|ONEZONE_IA|INTELLIGENT_TIERING|GLACIER|DEEP_ARCHIVE',
    ]
);
```

You can use `putFileAs()` Method As Well Like Below

```
Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs(
        'file path',
        $request->file('file'),
        'file name',
        [
            'StorageClass' => 'STANDARD|REDUCED_REDUNDANCY|STANDARD_IA|ONEZONE_IA|INTELLIGENT_TIERING|GLACIER|DEEP_ARCHIVE',
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't really find this answer on the internet. Hope it helps someone else.
If you want to set `StorageClass` on the disk level (once for every upload).

You can change it on the `config\filesystems.php`

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
            'options' => [
                'StorageClass' => 'INTELLIGENT_TIERING'
            ]
        ],
```

Other possible options...

```
        'ACL',
        'CacheControl',
        'ContentDisposition',
        'ContentEncoding',
        'ContentLength',
        'ContentType',
        'Expires',
        'GrantFullControl',
        'GrantRead',
        'GrantReadACP',
        'GrantWriteACP',
        'Metadata',
        'RequestPayer',
        'SSECustomerAlgorithm',
        'SSECustomerKey',
        'SSECustomerKeyMD5',
        'SSEKMSKeyId',
        'ServerSideEncryption',
        'StorageClass',
        'Tagging',
        'WebsiteRedirectLocation',
```

Ref: [thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem-aws-s3-v3/blob/3668f4aeafc08a463195a514d52b05d603cb981e/src/AwsS3Adapter.php#L38)

Comment: For a list of storage class values see this link under the `x-amz-storage-class` form field: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

Currently these are the valid values: `STANDARD | REDUCED_REDUNDANCY | GLACIER | GLACIER_IR | STANDARD_IA | ONEZONE_IA | INTELLIGENT_TIERING | DEEP_ARCHIVE`